# When to give up on getting results from an external web service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, http

I'm using [a gem](https://github.com/arikrak/ideone-gem/blob/master/lib/ideone.rb) to get code results from Ideone.com. The gem submits code to Ideone and then checks for the results page. It checks `timeout` times and then gives up if there's no result. The problem is it might give up too early, but I also don't want it to wait too long if there's not going to be a result. Is there a way to know when one should give up hope?

This is the relevant code:

```
   begin
      sleep 3  if i > 0
      res = JSON.load(
        Net::HTTP.post_form(
          URI.parse("http://ideone.com/ideone/Index/view/id/#{loc}/ajax/1"),
          {}
        ).body
      )
      i += 1
    end while res['status'] != '0' && i < timeout

    if i == timeout
      raise IdeoneError, "Timed out while waiting for code result."
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to adjust sleep timeout and number of attempts parameters. There is no absolute values suitable for each case, so you should pick some which are most appropriate for you application.

Unfortunatelly the gem code have both this parameters (3 seconds delay and 4 attempts) hardcoded so you don't have an elegant way to change them. So you can either fork the gem and change its code or try to monkey-patch the value of TIMEOUT constant with http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_set . However you won't be able to monkey-patch the delay between attempts value without rewriting method .run of the gem.

FYI. Net::HTTP has their own timeouts - how much time to wait for ideone.com connection and response. If they are exceeded Net::HTTP raises Timeout exception. The setters are

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-read_timeout-3D and #open_timeout=.

Comment: Thanks. I already forked the gem to get it to work. So I guess I should just lower the delay and raise the attempts? I was wondering if there would be a better way to know when to give up.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to retry more frequently than once every 3 seconds. I'd even increase it.

Only you can decide how long you can wait for the result. 

This code is synchronous and it blocks until timeout specified.
If you run  this code from a ruby script from some background task - you can wait for quite a long time. Like 3-5 minutes.

But if the code is run as part of processing of real user http requests you usually don't want to wait at all. Even 1 second is too much. So it is correct to implement some asynchronous checking with server side push or ajax long-poll.

Comment: its an ajax request, but user will be waiting for result. ideally i would want to give it to them within a few seconds, but its better to be late than to give "time out error". don't know best way to avoid the error.